# How do I put $_FILES content into binary var in PHP?

Tags: c#, php

I have a unity C# program which is uploading a binary file (with some data).
(which is kind of irrelvant but maybe not)

```
var form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("docid", "A");               
byte[] textarr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("just a sample text to be compressed and sent to server");
form.AddBinaryData("file", textarr,"file.tmp");                
string req = "my url";        
WWW www = new WWW(req,form);
```

I want to take the file content (as binary) so that I will be able to send into the database as binari in the PHP side.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$binaridata = ~$_FILES["file"]["name"] (what do i need to do here? tried
```

file_get_content etc, but it always yield some errors)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$binaryData = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

The file is stored at the path indicated by `tmp_name`, `name` is just the name given by the client and practically irrelevant.

Depending on how you talk to the database and what database, you *don't* want to read the entire file contents into a variable though. For instance, using Postgres via PDO, you'd do this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO ... VALUES (:file)');

$fh = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$stmt->bindParam(':file', $fh, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$stmt->execute();
```

The database adapter will read the file as a stream, which is much more economic than saving it in memory. Consult your database adapter's manual.

Comment: $binaryData = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); yes this works fine, its what i needed thanks.

Answer (score -1):

why not try 
    `$binaridata = $_FILES["file"]["name"];`
add the semicolon and remove the ~

Shadowpat